# .htaccess losing css dir

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

Hi there im using this code to rewrite

**This**: `index.php?page=articles&id=1`

**To**: `articles/1`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

The css changing and instead of searching /assets is searching for articles/assets.
All of the website taking from one template as OOP template so what can I do?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please provide CSS <link> code

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />

Answer (score 3):

Use "RewriteBase /" this will help.

Or you can use :

```
<base href="/">
```

tag in your HTML page header.

Comment: @user3050136 If this solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)